# Defined Variable (Long) Change within Subroutine Not Updated

Tags: excel, vba, variables, dimension

I have a userform that moves objects (employee names) around on a worksheet so that managers can move employees into a different department (different row grouping on the worksheet) if necessary.  The problem I've encountered is that when I define the initial row that belongs to the employee name and then move that row via Selection.Cut and Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, I can no longer call the new location of the employee row, because this has changed and any lines of code that follow still recognize the initial employee row that was identified in the userform code.

```
Dim UserRow As Long
Dim UserMatrix As String

Dim CCIRow As Long
Dim CCIRange As String
Dim CEMRow As Long
Dim CEMRange As String
Dim MANRow As Long
Dim MANRange As String

UserRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(UserName, Range("A1:A300"), 0)
UserMatrix = "B" & UserRow

    CCIRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("CCI / MDI", Range("A1:A300"), 0) + 1
    Let CCIRange = "A" & CCIRow
    CEMRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("CE / Marketing", Range("A1:A300"), 0) + 1
    Let CEMRange = "A" & CEMRow
    MANRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Management", Range("A1:A300"), 0) + 1
    Let MANRange = "A" & MANRow
    OTHRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Other", Range("A1:A300"), 0) + 1

Sheet3.Rows(UserRow).Select
Selection.Cut

If UserDept = "CCI / MDI" Then
Sheet3.Rows(CCIRow).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Sheet3.Range(UserMatrix).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Clear                                                             

    Sheet3.Range("MATRIX_ROW").Select
    Selection.Copy                                                              

    Sheet3.Range(UserMatrix).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial PASTE:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Sheet3.Range(CCIRange).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column)).Sort _
        key1:=Range(CCIRange), order1:=xlAscending
End If

If UserDept = "CE / Marketing" Then
Sheet3.Rows(CEMRow).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Sheet3.Range(UserMatrix).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Clear                                                             

    Sheet3.Range("MATRIX_ROW").Select
    Selection.Copy                                                              

    Sheet3.Range(UserMatrix).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial PASTE:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Sheet3.Range(CEMRange).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column)).Sort _
        key1:=Range(CEMRange), order1:=xlAscending
End If

If UserDept = "Management" Then
Sheet3.Rows(MANRow).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Sheet3.Range(UserMatrix).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Clear

    Sheet3.Range("MATRIX_ROW").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheet3.Range(UserMatrix).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial PASTE:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Sheet3.Range(MANRange).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column)).Sort _
        key1:=Range(MANRange), order1:=xlAscending
End If
```

My question:  Is there any way that I can update the value of a define dimension variable (i.e. Dim) within a subroutine as it changes?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: THANK YOU!  Resetting the dimension after the move was exactly what solved my issue!  There's a lot going on in the application I developed, and this small snipet was causing me so much frustration.  I owe you a couple beers my friend!!

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer, just in case anyone else has the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking can you change the value of `UserRow` then the answer is "Yes". 
All you have to do is assign it the value of the row number of wherever you pasted it.

I'm having trouble understanding the code with so many `Select`, `ActiveCell` and `Selection` bits, but it might be something like `UserRow = CCIRow`.

(Alternatively, you can just reset it by using your `UserRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(UserName, Range("A1:A300"), 0)` statement again after the move.)